# ARIMA summary showing as SARIMAX

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, arima

I have an ARIMA(1,1,1) model I am trying to fit to a dataframe of stock prices. The index of the dataframe is a date.

The code below compiles but it produces a SARIMAX summary and not ARIMA (see image).

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
dataset_for_prediction.index = dataset_for_prediction.index.to_period('B')
model = ARIMA(dataset_for_prediction['Adj Close'], order=(1,1,1))
model_fit = model.fit()
print(model_fit.summary())
```

[image]

How can I then plot the actual results. I have tried the following but it just produces a horizontal line.

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_predict
plot_predict(model_fit)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to print the predicted values:

```
print(model_fit.predict())
```

Output

```
Date
2014-12-31      0.000000
2015-01-02    108.382622
2015-01-05    109.424271
2015-01-06    107.839921
2015-01-07    105.537888
                 ...    
2022-04-25    133.380821
2022-04-26    134.080382
2022-04-27    131.454924
2022-04-28    130.273586
2022-04-29    130.850081
```

When drawing this picture(first element 0):
[image]
excluded the first element

```
fig = plot_predict(model_fit, start=dataset_for_prediction.index[1], end=dataset_for_prediction.index[-1], ax=ax)
```

[image]
All code:

```
import yfinance as yf
from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_predict
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset_for_prediction = yf.download('IBM', start='2015-01-01', end='2022-04-30')

dataset_for_prediction.index = dataset_for_prediction.index.to_period('B')
model = ARIMA(dataset_for_prediction['Adj Close'], order=(1, 1, 1))
model_fit = model.fit()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = dataset_for_prediction['Adj Close'].plot(ax=ax)
fig = plot_predict(model_fit, start=dataset_for_prediction.index[1], end=dataset_for_prediction.index[-1], ax=ax)
legend = ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks. What is the reason we have to exclude the first value, I don't understand why including it causes only a straight line to be produced and it omits all other values...

Comment: Yes. Because the minimum of the graph becomes 0, not for example 100 (an approximate figure). Because of this, the rest of the values seem so small. You can highlight these values and zoom in to make sure it's not a straight line.

Comment: Also note: ax = dataset_for_prediction['Adj Close'].plot(ax=ax). This line displayed the values themselves, which were used for prediction, and they are all displayed from the first element to the last.

Comment: if it is interesting to predict a few steps ahead, then I implemented it [here](https://github.com/quant12345/ARIMA-dynamic-graph). But more and more I come to the conclusion that increments (differences) must be applied and predicted. And then use these predicted increments to restore the series. For example, add the first value to the opening price and then add the values cumulatively. Since the data is not stationary and the parameter d in ARIMA, even with 2 gives mostly straight up or down.